# Elements in commutator subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

We know that $|G| < \infty$ and $|G:Z(G)|^2 < |G'|$. Show that $G'$ contains elements
which are not commutators.
($G'$ is a commutator subgroup of G)

Can I get any hints?

Comment: Is $G$ a subgroup of $G'$?

Comment: I edited the question and gave an explanation

Comment: Hmm. By definition $G'$ consists entirely of commutators of $G$ (if I'm understanding you correctly).  I afraid your question makes less sense now.

Comment: $G'$ consists all products of commutators and a product of commutators does not have to be a commutator itself

Comment: Oh yes.  Sorry, I forgot.

Comment: Hint: if $a,b \in G$ and $z, w \in Z(G)$, then $[a,b] = [az,bw].$